# How do I copy a collection into another, as a sub collection? Angularfire/ Angular/ Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire

I have two collections

collection 1-  modules,

collection 2-  profile >> modules (as a sub collection in profile collection)

I want to copy all documents from collection 1 into collection 2 ( one time operation )

Below is what I tried

```
private afs:AngularFirestore;

this.afs.collection('modules').valueChanges().subscribe(vals =>{
        vals.forEach(moduleFromRepo =>{
          this.afs.collection('profiles').doc('userid1').collection('modules').add(moduleFromRepo);    
        })
      });
```

Problem with this code - Although this works for the first time, and then every time a new document is added to collection 1, the entire collection 1 is re-copied to collection 2, such that I be getting several duplicated document copies in collection 2.

Also, is my approach correct in the first place? What is the proper way to code to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you trying to copy everything a single time, or are you trying to copy changes to documents, as they happen over time?  Please edit the question to be clear what your goal is.  Your code is using a realtime listener and is going to be delivered the entire set of documents with every change.

Comment: I would rather make a function trigger using `onUpdate` event as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events. The main idea would be checking the upcoming data from the collection1, as `functions.firestore.document('modules/{moduleId}')` then use the user Id (if the updated module document has this data) to get the collection2 document by id and save into its subcollection

Comment: Then why don't you write a trigger function, as you see in that documentation, instead of doing this in the client app?

Comment: Its a one time operation ( edited in the question as well). Hence I think I don't need to create a trigger. Also I found a workaround, using take(1) ( rxjs operator )-I achieved what I wanted.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and accept it as correct, so other can have a clear solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also I found a workaround using take(1), which is a rxjs operator